# How to find rogue access points?

Tags: wifi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tracking down a rogue access point](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10783/tracking-down-a-rogue-access-point)

Rogue access points can pose a threat, when employees connect to them.  What are some techniques that can be used to find these devices, and what actions can be taken against them?